# Tkinter Return key bind doesn't work due to class structure

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I understand how to bind keys when it's just on a simple frame but since I built my app in a different way, I can't seem to figure out how to bind the return key to press the button or run the function that the button is bounded to. I've been searching for a similar question by others on the website but I haven't found one similar to mine.

I've toned down the rest of my code and have it below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class POS(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (ErrorPage, MainPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise() 


class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(fill = BOTH)

        button = Button(frame, text = "OK", command = self.bindHello)
        button.pack(pady=5, padx=10)

        frame.bind("<Return>", self.bindHello)
        self.bind("<Return>", self.bindHello)

    def bindHello(self, event=None):
        print("HELLO1")


#Yes this doesn't do anything but I need it for the frame container as set before
class ErrorPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(fill = BOTH)

        button = Button(frame, text = "OK", command = self.bindHello)
        button.pack(pady=5, padx=10)

        frame.bind("<Return>", self.bindHello)

    def bindHello(self, event=None):
        print("HELLO2")


app = POS()
app.mainloop()
```

Simple Button bind I had intended to work as is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

def callback(event=None):
    print("Hello " + entry.get())

entry = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable = entry, width = 15)
e.pack()

b = Button(master, text="OK", command = callback)
b.pack()
master.bind("<Return>", callback)

mainloop()
```

I would just like to have a simple button bind like the one above but I can't seem to find a way for my main program to work. I think it's due to the way I structured my app, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? What is it doing, and how is that different than what you expect? Are you aware that frames don't get the keyboard focus by default?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm not entirely sure about why it doesn't work, but I think that it's something to do with how I reference the parent function/widget. I've tried other ways of binding the key but haven't really found much success.
In my actual program, I have an entry box together with the button and when a user is finished typing whatever on the box and the "return" key is pressed then it goes to the next command.
Also, I'm not aware that frames don't default keyboard focus, I'll take a look a bit more.

Comment: @Miggy Please provide the way that you can bind to a frame that behaves the way you want. We can't reliably guess what's on your mind.

Comment: @Nae I added a button bind that I would like to imitate on the first code set that I shared. It's just a simple button bind wherein the value inside the entry box is taken and printed out or saved inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your sample you bind to the window itself. You can do so in the other one as well in a number of ways:

```
#1 bind to page object's direct parent, which happens to be a Toplevel-like
#self.master.bind('<Return>', self.bindHello)

#2 recursively search page object's parents, and bind when it's a Toplevel-like
#self.winfo_toplevel().bind('<Return>', self.bindHello)

#3 bind to page object's inner frame's parent's parent, which happens to be a Toplevel-like
#frame.master.master.bind('<Return>', self.bindHello)

#4 recursively search page object's inner frame's parents, and bind when it's a Toplevel-like
frame.winfo_toplevel().bind('<Return>', self.bindHello)
```

Comment: I will try it when I get the chance, I think I tried the first one before but I'll have to check again. Thanks! I'll get back to you when I get to test it out

Comment: @Miggy What's the error? perhaps replace `master` with `parent`.

Comment: I tried #1 again and it didn't call the function i.e. the bind didn't work. changing master to parent doesn't work since parent isn't the class doesn't have the attribute parent. I think my code was a little bit different from what I have above but #2 surely works so I'll just work with that one.